# Determining if two BackGroundWorker strings return true

Tags: c#, multithreading

Questions:
     What is the best way to check if two BackgroundWorkers returned true as there values
     or if neither returned true, or only one did.

Additional Info:

I have two BackgroundWorker currently checking to see if two SQL connections are
 valid and returning a value depending whether a connection was made successfully.

The code is as follows:

```
private void btnTestSConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker work1 = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
            BackgroundWorker work2 = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
            work1.RunWorkerCompleted += (item, a) =>
            {
                //need to figure out this portion
            };
            work2.RunWorkerCompleted += (item, a) =>
            {
                //need to figure out this portion
            };

            work1.DoWork += doWork;
            work2.DoWork += doWork;

            SourceString.InitialCatalog = txtSSourceDatabase.Text;
            work1.RunWorkerAsync(SourceString.ConnectionString);
            SourceString.InitialCatalog = txtSSystemDatabase.Text;
            work2.RunWorkerAsync(SourceString.ConnectionString);
        }

DoWorkEventHandler doWork = (sender, e) =>
        {
            SqlConnection Connection;
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        using (Connection = new SqlConnection((string)e.Argument))
                        {
                            Connection.Open();
                        }
                        e.Result = true;
                    }
                    catch (SqlException c)
                    {
                        e.Result = false;
                    }
                }
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may returned a KeyValuePair where the first bool represent the which worker were used (true for work1, false for work2) and the second bool is the returned value of the DoWork method like this:

```
work1.DoWork += doWork;
work2.DoWork += doWork;

work1.RunWorkerAsync(true);
work2.RunWorkerAsync(false);

private void doWork(s, e)
{
  var kvp = new KeyValuePair<bool, bool>;
  kvp.Key = e.Argument as bool; // this indicate which of the worker returned a value
  ...
  using (Connection = new SqlConnection((string)e.Argument))
  {
    Connection.Open();
  }
  kvp.Value = true; // this is the result of your connection test
  ...
  e.Result = kvp
};
```

Now on your RunWorkerCompleted, you can cast the Result to a KeyValuePair and get if weither the work1 or work2 returned a which value.

```
b.RunWorkerCompleted += (item, a) =>
{
  var kvp = a.Result as KeyValuePair<bool, bool>;
  //kvp.Key == true mean this is the work1
  //kvp.Value is the SQL connection test
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [wait handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) to trigger an event when each complete.

```
private void btnTestSConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventWaitHandle firstComplete = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
            EventWaitHandle secondComplete = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

                bool overallResult = false;

            BackgroundWorker work1 = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
            BackgroundWorker work2 = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
            work1.RunWorkerCompleted += (item, a) =>
            {
                firstComplete.Set();
                //need to figure out this portion
                overallResult &= a.Result 
            };
            work2.RunWorkerCompleted += (item, a) =>
            {
                secondComplete.Set();
                //need to figure out this portion
                overallResult &= a.Result 
            };

            work1.DoWork += doWork;
            work2.DoWork += doWork;

            SourceString.InitialCatalog = txtSSourceDatabase.Text;
            work1.RunWorkerAsync(SourceString.ConnectionString);
            SourceString.InitialCatalog = txtSSystemDatabase.Text;
            work2.RunWorkerAsync(SourceString.ConnectionString);

            // Wait on First will not go until set
            firstComplete.WaitOne();

            // Wait on second
            secondComplete.WaitOne();

            // Both now complete
            //Do what you need to now
        }

DoWorkEventHandler doWork = (sender, e) =>
        {
            SqlConnection Connection;
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        using (Connection = new SqlConnection((string)e.Argument))
                        {
                            Connection.Open();
                        }
                        e.Result = true;
                    }
                    catch (SqlException c)
                    {
                        e.Result = false;
                    }
                }
        };
```

Comment: This code will deadlock.  Don't call WaitOne() on the UI thread.

Comment: That is very true.  So before you want to do this, spin off to another thread.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `volatile` keyword on a boolean variable. and change its value inside the thread. and check it after complete or any time at work process